# Unable to update data in Realtime Database

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

So I currently have a database in Firebase containing information that I am displaying to users. And as an admin, I want to update the information. However, when I try to update it, a new record is added instead into Firebase Realtime Database.

This is the code that displays all the records in Realtime Database and an edit icon that redirects it to the update page:

```
class _UpdateDestinationsState extends State<UpdateDestinations> {
  final destdatabaseref = FirebaseDatabase.instance
      .reference()
      .child('Database')
      .child('DestinationsandActivities')
      .orderByChild("category")
      .equalTo("Destination");

  @override
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.white), //add this line here
        backgroundColor: Color(0xFF3d5a89),
        elevation: 0,
        centerTitle: true,
        title: const Text('Update Destinations',
            style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 18,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                color: Colors.white)),
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
          child: FirebaseAnimatedList(
              query: destdatabaseref,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, DataSnapshot snapshot,
                  Animation<double> animation, int index) {
                return ListTile(
                  title: Text(snapshot.value['name']),
                  trailing: IconButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => UpdatePage(
                                  name: snapshot.value['name'],
                                  description: snapshot.value['description'],
                                  id: snapshot.value['id'],
                                )));
                      },
                      icon: Icon(Icons.edit)),
                );
              })),
    );
  }
}
```

And this is the code for the Update Page where you can edit information:

```
class UpdatePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String name;
  final String description;
  final String id;

  UpdatePage(
      {Key? key,
      required this.name,
      required this.description,
      required this.id})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  _UpdatePageState createState() => _UpdatePageState();
}

class _UpdatePageState extends State<UpdatePage> {
  final destdatabaseref = FirebaseDatabase.instance
      .reference()
      .child('Database')
      .child('DestinationsandActivities');

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final nameController = TextEditingController();
    final descriptionController = TextEditingController();

    setState(() {
      nameController.text = widget.name;
      descriptionController.text = widget.description;
    });
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.white),
          backgroundColor: Color(0xFF3d5a89),
          elevation: 0,
          centerTitle: true,
          title: const Text('Update Destinations',
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 18,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                  color: Colors.white)),
        ),
        body: Form(
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                TextFormField(
                  controller: nameController,
                  autofocus: false,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: 'Name',
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 10),
                TextFormField(
                  controller: descriptionController,
                  autofocus: false,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: 'Description',
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  ),
                ),
                TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      updateData(widget.name, widget.description, widget.id);
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                    },
                    child: Text('Update')),
                TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                    },
                    child: Text('Cancel')),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }

  void updateData(String name, String description, var key) {
    Map<String, String> newvalue = {'name': name, 'description': description};
    destdatabaseref.child(key).update(newvalue);
  }
}
```

With this code, I get this type of record added into my Realtime Database when I click update textbutton:
[image: Error]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the mistake.
The `updateData(widget.name, widget.description, widget.id);` should be: `updateData(nameController.text, descriptionController.text, widget.id);` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is getting the id.
Realtime will use generated key (id) if you pass null value, I never used `FirebaseAnimatedList` before, but I saw an example where they accessed the key with `snapshot.key`....
But I'm sure it not `snapshot.value['id']` because in your structure there is no id with name and decoration, and it will be returned as object so the id won't be a field to access it.
So try first to print `snapshot.value['id']` if it contains the id then skip my answer, if its null try `snapshot.key`, see how snapshot is structured with FirebaseAnimatedList if that didn't work either.

Comment: Hey, thanks! I think that might work. However, I'm declaring the ```snapshot.key``` as var in ```UpdatePage``` class instead of final string and I get "```This class (or a class that this class inherits from) is marked as '@immutable', but one or more of its instance fields aren't final: UpdatePage.id```"

Comment: You don't need to do that, keep the `UpdatePage` class as it is, just change what you pass for it as: `onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => UpdatePage(
                                  name: snapshot.value['name'],
                                  description: snapshot.value['description'],
                                 id: snapshot.key, //<-- here
                                )));
                      },`

Comment: I did that but it says that ```The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'```.

Comment: I don't know if you know what that mean, but its related to null-safety, where '?' means that that string can be null, if you don't add it then that value can't be null, which is what happening here, where UpdatePage can't take null value for any of its parameters. To solve this there is multiple simple ways: - (Not good) allow UpdatePage to take null value by use '?':  `final String? id;` which is not good because you need the id. - check the value before calling it:`onPressed:() { if(snapshot.key!=null){Navigator.of(context)...}`For more checking(and stop the error) pass:`snapshot.key??''`

Comment: I tried it! Definitely takes the ```The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'``` error away but the data still can't be updated.